# Can data be stored in both local and remote storage

Tags: prometheus

When prometheus collects metrics data from agent, it can save data in local or remote storage, can it be stored in both? so I can use promQL to query the data and at the same time, using another tool to query it from remote storage?
I am newbie on prom and did not find answer from prom doc, thanks for any help.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

It can be stored locally, or it can be stored locally and remotely. Similarly you can query locally, or locally and remotely via Prometheus.